# Pebble.js works on emulator but fails on watch

Tags: javascript, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I'm trying to build a small tracker on CloudPebble but I am failing all the time. I'm starting with something simple, and it is only working on the emulator.

I'm following this example:

http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/pebblejs/#wakeup-schedule-options-callback-event

On the emulator runs, more or less, fine, but when I try to run it on the pebble time itself it reports an error:
Wakeup set failed: invalidArgument

Why? Is exactly the same code!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that by the time the app gets installed on the watch, the wake-up time has already occurred and now it's trying to schedule an event for the past which is giving you the "invalidArgument" error.

Try set the wake up time to be even later than just one minute.